# NSPredicate with SortDiscriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios7

Currently I am trying to use NSFetchResultsController and I am using a predicate to fetch those results. Is there a possibility rather than using sort descriptor, to get the results sorted based on the predicate query using the keys in the array?

Comment: `NSPredicate` is only used for filtering, afaik.

Comment: Just paste some example what code do you want to get. Why are you trying to go around sort descriptors? They were invented for sorting in the first place. You can put part of your predicate query into sort descriptor, but i must know the query and what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Terminus miscPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key IN %@", person]; where person is an array of selected keys that I want to query. However I want to keep the order of Person was selected.

Comment: See my answer in question that is an original to your duplicate